# Error in pivot table Must declare the scalar variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I have a SQL with the following:

```
DECLARE @AssociadoID int

WITH BaseQuery AS 
(
    SELECT
        ValorPago,
        YEAR(Data) AS OrderYear,
        MONTH(Data) AS OrderMonth
    FROM 
        T_Eventos
    WHERE 
        ([AssociadoID] = @AssociadoID)
)
SELECT
    OrderYear,
    [1] AS [January],
    [2] AS [February],
    [3] AS [March],
    [4] AS [April],
    [5] AS [May],
    [6] AS [June],
    [7] AS [July],
    [8] AS [August],
    [9] AS [September],
    [10] AS [October],
    [11] AS [November],
    [12] AS [December]
FROM 
    BaseQuery 
PIVOT 
    (SUM(ValorPago) FOR OrderMonth IN ([1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9], [10], [11], [12])) AS PVT
ORDER BY 
    January DESC
```

About this query, if  I remove `DECLARE @AssociadoID`, the IDE Visual Studio just returns empty query, even content rows. But if I remove from the query build, it's said I must declare the scalar variable.

My purpose about this block is just to show the data from the people is logged on system

What I should to do to resolve this!?

Comment: I think it may just be a missing semicolon before the `with`.

Comment: I'm not following. You just add `;` between the two statements.

Answer (score 0):

I´ve found a solution:
Just the end of first select, just add the parameter:

```
SELECT ValorPago, YEAR(Data) AS OrderYear,
MONTH(Data) AS OrderMonth
FROM T_Eventos Where AssociadoID = @AssociadoID
```

It´s not necessary put DECLARE @AssociadoID Int on the beggining

After this, just set the SelectParameter like as will :)

Comment: I'm glad you got this figured out. As a tip, I think we could have helped you better if you had indicated that you were creating a parameterized query inside other code. We didn't really have the full context of your question.